# Integration problem.

Tags: integration

Given the simple first order reaction $ A -> P $ derive the integrated rate law.

$$\frac{d[A]}{dt} = -k[A]$$
Collect terms:
$$\frac{d[A]}{[A]} = -kdt$$

Now for the bit I need help with, the integration: 
Apparently the integrated form of $\frac{d[A]}{[A]}= ln[A]$ but I'm struggling to see exactly how.

The next step (usually omitted)I think should be to split the fraction before integration
$$\frac{d[A]}{1}\frac{1}{[A]}=d[A]\frac{1}{[A]}=-kt$$

$$\int{d[A]\frac{1}{[A]}}=\int{-kt}$$

$$\int{d[A]}\int{\frac{1}{[A]}}=\int{-kt}$$

Now, to evaluate this I use the general integration law for a constant $\int{[A]  dt} = [A]t + C$ and reciprocal  $\int{\frac{1}{[A]}=ln[A]+C}$. Therefore $$\int{d[A]}\int{\frac{1}{[A]}}=[A]t + C1+ ln[A]+C2=\int{\frac{d[A]}{[A]}}$$

I know this is wrong because the textbooks say something different but I don't know how to correct it. Can anyone help?

Please be specific with every step (even if you think its trivial).Thank you.

Comment: You need to recapitulate basic integration theory: $\int dx f(x) \neq \int dx\int f(x)$!!! The expression on the right is not only wrong but completly ill defined!